# Why does my python tkinter item move away after being dragged?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I'm moving the item from the canvas. The problem is that every time I click on the item, the cursor moves, but doesn't stay where I clicked. It appears to be moving to the NW, but I can't find anything related to it and I don't know how I can stop it from doing so.

Here's the code for the parent window:

```py
window = tk.Tk();
window.title("City pallete");
window.geometry("620x420");
window.resizable(False, False);

opencv.createPreview(window);
```

In the file with the parent window, I create an `OpenCV` object, call its `createPreview` method, using the parent window as its only argument:

```py
  def createPreview(self, root):
        # create preview instance object
        self.preview_window = Preview(root);
```

And here's the accompanying code for the `Preview` class:

```
class Preview(tk.Toplevel):

    COLORS = [
        "black", 
        "white", 
        "gray",
        "silver", 
        "maroon", 
        "red",
        "purple", 
    ]

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('462x1920');
        self.title('Toplevel Window');
        self.resizable(False, True);

        self.background = tk.PhotoImage(file = "./assets/test.png");
        
        # background image
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width = 462, height = 1920);
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.background);
        
        self.position = tk.Label(self, text = "hola");
        self.canvas.create_window(100, 300, window = self.position);

        # color entry 
        colors_text = tk.Label(self, text = "number of colors:");
        self.canvas.create_window(110, 680, window = colors_text);
   
        self.number_colors = tk.Entry(self, bg = "white", fg = "black");
        self.number_colors.insert(0, "6");
        self.canvas.create_window(150, 700, window = self.number_colors);
        
        # create bars
        self.createBars();

        # color entry 
        render_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Render", bg = "white", command = self.resetColors);
        self.canvas.create_window(300, 700, window = render_button);

        # adding event
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.moveColors);

        self.canvas.pack();

    def moveColors(self, e):
        self.canvas.moveto("line", e.x, e.y + 100);
        value = tk.StringVar();
        value.set(f"X: {e.x} Y: {e.y}");
        self.position.config(text = value.get());
     
    def createBars(self):
        
        size = (200, 50);

        for i in range(int(self.number_colors.get())):
            self.canvas.create_line(
                size[0], i*size[1], size[0], size[1]+(i*size[1]), 
                fill = self.COLORS[i], 
                width = 10, 
                tags = ("line", self.COLORS[i])
            );
           
    def resetColors(self):
        self.canvas.delete("line");
        self.createBars();
```

Here is a gif showing the problem:

[image: a gif showing the problem]

Comment: Please provide a complete, but minimal [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley hey mate, uploaded a gif, the resolution is bad cause max is 2mib lol

Comment: We don't need a gif, we need a [mcve].

Comment: but thats all i have, i just create the bars the call function with the event

Comment: You must have more code than what you posted. The code you posted doesn't import tkinter,  it doesn't create a root window, it never creates `self.canvas` or self.position, or defines a class to put it in, it never calls `createBars` or `moveColors`. The code you posted doesn't add any bindings. And so on. Please read the link I included in my comments.

Comment: @BryanOakley go it, edited now is all the code where i create the window with the items

Comment: This code won't run. Did you try running _this exact code_? It attempts to use `self.number_colors` before defining it.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, just got the error, changed it

Comment: This kind of thing is USUALLY a coordinate mapping problem, where you're receiving coordinates that are relative to the screen or relative to some component, and then you try to use them to adjust some other component.  You need to check whether the x and y you are receiving is relative to the canvas or relative to the screen.